# SSMA cannot convert Access query to a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I want to convert query to a view on a sql server. The SS Migration Assistant is chocking on the following query:

```sql
SELECT 
    FechInventory.ID AS skuID, 
    FechInventory.ItemNo, 
    IIf(InStr(3,[ItemNo],".")>0,Mid([ItemNo],3,InStr(1,[ItemNo],".")-3),InStr(3,[ItemNo],Len([ItemNo]))) AS ItemStyle,
    IIf(InStr(1,[ItemNo],"/")>0,Mid([ItemNo],InStr(1,[ItemNo],".")+1,InStr(1,[ItemNo],"/")-InStr(1,[ItemNo],".")-1),Mid([ItemNo],InStr(1,[ItemNo],".")+1,Len([ItemNo]))) AS Size1, 
    IIf(InStr(1,[ItemNo],"/")>0,Mid([ItemNo],InStr(1,[ItemNo],"/")+1,Len([ItemNo])-InStr(1,[ItemNo],"/")),"") AS Size2, 
    FechInventory.Desc, 
    FechInventory.Qty, 
    FechInventory.sCost, 
    [sCost]*0.18 AS gcCost, 
    [scost]*0.18*[qty] AS gcLineCost, 
    InStr(3,[ItemNo],".") AS FirstPeriod, 
    InStr(1,[ItemNo],"/") AS FirstSlash, 
    Len([ItemNo]) AS ItemNoLength, 
    FechInventory.Brand, 
    Brands.[Brand Name], 
    FechInventory.ProductType, 
    ProductTypes.ProductTypeName, 
    FechInventory.Gender, 
    Genders.GenderName, 
    FechInventory.Sleeve, 
    SleeveLengths.SleeveLength, 
    FechInventory.Color, 
    Colors.ColorName, 
    Fabrics.FabricTypeID, 
    Fabrics.FabricName
FROM 
    (
        Colors 
        RIGHT JOIN 
        (
            SleeveLengths 
            RIGHT JOIN 
            (
                Genders 
                RIGHT JOIN 
                (
                    (
                        FechInventory 
                        LEFT JOIN 
                        Brands 
                            ON FechInventory.Brand = Brands.BrandID
                    ) 
                    LEFT JOIN 
                    ProductTypes 
                        ON FechInventory.ProductType = ProductTypes.ProductTypeID
                ) 
                    ON Genders.GenderID = FechInventory.Gender
            ) 
                ON SleeveLengths.SleeveID = FechInventory.Sleeve
        ) 
            ON Colors.ColorID = FechInventory.Color
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN 
    Fabrics 
        ON FechInventory.FabricType = Fabrics.FabricTypeID
ORDER BY FechInventory.ItemNo;
```

It gives this error:

- SSMA error messages:
- A2SS0058: Following SQL statement is not supported and cannot be converted:

What gives? Anything stick out?

Comment: My immediate guess is that it is barking at the double quotes... If that is the case, how can I modify the access schema within the SSMA (not my access database) to make it work?

Comment: Nothing seems obvious. If you can, start by bracketing all the table and field names in this query to see if SSMA is getting confused and trying to convert a field/table to a function that does not have the valid parameters. If it still breaks, try removing the three IIF() fields to see if SSMA is getting confused by this. These functions do not exist in SQL Server but I would think SSMA should be able to convert them. They are straight forward.